# Display objects and their foreign key objects

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Need some help with displaying data.

**models.py**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name='brands', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand.name + " - " + self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def car_view(request):

    # pls halp
```

How to display list of Brands and after each brand a list of cars? Example is shown below.

```
<html>
    <ul>
    <li>Toyota</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Corolla</li>
        <li>Avensis</li>
        <li>Yaris</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Volkswagen</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Golf</li>
        <li>Transporter</li>
        <li>Passat</li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and how did it fail?

Comment: I've tried to get objects from database with objects.get()
I only know how to show all brands and all cars. But certain cars under their foreign key brand.. no result

Comment: @newObject first correct your `related_name` value to correct meaning something like `cars` not `brand` check my answer for reference

Answer (score 4):

First of all correct the model related_name,

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name='cars', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand.name + " - " + self.name
```

You can access all cars from `Brand` model instance as `brand.cars.all()`

```
def car_view(request):  
    return render("list.html", {'brand_list': Brand.objects.all()})
```

template will be similar to

```
<!-- list.html -->
{% block content %}
     {% for brand in brand_list %}
          {{ brand.name }}
          {% for car in brand.cars.all %}
              {{car.name}}
          {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, little typo there.. `brand.cars.all()`  gives me brand with it's cars, because in views there has to be a certain pk. But i need to show all brands with their cars on one page. Do i need to loop them somehow in views.py?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've got it now. Its that simple!?!??? I think I even saw something like that but after all day searching and not knowing how it really works my brains just...  :D well thanks again

Comment: if there was some correction needed in the answer do it so @newObject to help others :)

Comment: is this possible to be reversed?. like, id like to query the car first with filters and display its brand.

Thanks you.